# Avoid 'Reloaded modules: <module_name>' message in Python

Tags: python, import, module, warnings, spyder

I am getting the above mentioned error:

```
'Reloaded modules: <module_name>'
```

Since I want to keep my code as it is, i'd like to disable this warning. How can this be done? I am using Spyder 3.2.3.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2325

Comment: Thank you I already found this. Quoting: "Have a look in the Console section of the preferences, in the Advanced tab. You can either disable the message or the UMR completely". But I neither find a Console section nor an option to disable UMR or the messages I wound like to disable.

Comment: try tools->preferences->python interpreter

Comment: Or try: `import warnings` and than 
`warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="Reloaded modules: <module_name>")`

Comment: Thank you I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: I am sorry, this does not help to ignore the error. Might there be a difference between Python and IPython consoles?

Comment: @msg, this is just a warning, and it's only generated when you run code inside Spyder. As @andi mentioned, you can deactivate our UMR by going to `Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter`.

Comment: Thank you Carlos! That did the trick. I simply did not find this option since I did not know what to look for.

Answer (score 21):

Go to Tools -> Preferences -> Python Interpreter and you will find User Module Reloader. Just deselect the checkbox with text as Show reloaded module list.

Answer (score 8):

In spyder 2.3 you need to do the following:

Go to `Tools -> Preferences -> Console -> Advanced settings`
or `Tools -> Preferences -> Python interpreter in Spyder 5` (added thanks to @Osama El-Ghonimy)

[image]

then scroll down to:

[image]

desellect `Enable UMR`

Click on `Apply` (Anwenden) and restart Spyder.

The error should be gone now...

Comment: This is now found under Tools >> Preferences >>Python interpreter in Spyder 5