# Spyder Setup - Additional output console

Tags: python, spyder

I started learning Python yesterday and just installed Spyder as my IDE.

I have read the help docs and checked on Youtube but not find the info I was looking for.  So when I run my print("hello world") script, it shows all these extra info in the console - including the path to my script;

```
Reloaded modules: ipykernel, ipykernel._version, ipykernel.connect, ipykernel.kernelapp, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, ipykernel.iostream, jupyter_client.session, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, ipykernel.heartbeat, ipykernel.ipkernel, IPython.utils.tokenutil, ipykernel.comm, ipykernel.comm.manager, ipykernel.comm.comm, ipykernel.kernelbase, tornado.queues, tornado.locks, ipykernel.jsonutil, ipykernel.zmqshell, IPython.core.payloadpage, ipykernel.displayhook, ipykernel.datapub, ipykernel.serialize, ipykernel.pickleutil, ipykernel.codeutil, ipykernel.eventloops, ipykernel.parentpoller, pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, win32api, win32security, ntsecuritycon, IPython.core.completerlib, storemagic, autoreload, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model, PIL.PngImagePlugin, PIL.ImageChops, PIL.ImageFile, PIL.ImagePalette, PIL.GimpGradientFile, PIL.GimpPaletteFile, PIL.ImageColor, PIL.PaletteFile, PIL.ImageSequence, dateutil.rrule, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d, ipykernel.pylab, ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, ipykernel.pylab.config, spyder, spyder.pil_patch
Hello World
```

How do I get rid of these?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what happens?

Comment: Does that help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485628/avoid-reloaded-modules-module-name-message-in-python

Comment: Glad to hear that you are starting your journey with python.  Hope the above comment help resolve your issue with Spyder.  Also, as you start out, look into [Jupyter Notebook/Lab](https://jupyter.org/) as an alternate IDE.  A good introduction to Jupyter Notebook can be found [here](https://realpython.com/jupyter-notebook-introduction/).

Comment: Hi FloLie, please see below

Comment: @DIFA1 what are you refering to?